# Call Async a Restfull WebService in Android Java

Tags: java, android, web-services

I need to make a call to the webservice in android java and another class calls it. I the end, showing the ws response in UI.

I've done the webservice. Only that part of the "asynchronous" is not working properly.

This is my webservice, receiving three strings:

```js
public class WebServiceRestFull extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    protected ProgressDialog dialog;


    public String wsURL;
    public String wsFunction;
    public String wsInput;

    public int codeHTTP;
    public String messageHTTP;
    public String strResponse;


    public WebServiceRestFull(Context act)
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(act);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Wait please...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
String url = wsURL + wsFunction;
        String inputCoded = EncodeString(wsInput);

        HttpURLConnection request;

        URL urlToRequest = new URL(url);
        request = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();

        request.setDoOutput(true);
        request.setDoInput(true);
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(request.getOutputStream());
        outputStreamWriter.write("\""+inputCoded+"\"");
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();

        codeHTTP = request.getResponseCode();
        messageHTTP = request.getResponseMessage();

        InputStream is = request.getInputStream();

        String resp = convertStreamToString(is);
        strResponse = DecodeString(resp);

        request.disconnect();

       
        return strResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR";
    }
    }      
}
```

On the other side, in the "Android Activity" I call this asynchronous class as follows:

```
WebServiceRestFull web = new WebServiceRestFull(this);
web.wsURL = "http://someurl.com/rest/etc";
web.wsFunction = "login";
web.wsInput = "mike";
web.execute();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

The problem is that this is not actually do an asynchronous call and the results usually are not received by the webservice .

Is there any simple way to do this or am I doing wrong in some side as the call to webservice or own webservice class ?

Sorry for my english.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use a Thread.sleep(1000) ? instead use a callback method to get the results after result.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the way you created and excecuted this asynctask

Just please don't use Thread.sleep();

And the issue is clearly in the doInBackground() method which code we don't have here

Comment: Try to watch the logs, if there is an issue during the request there should be some warning

Answer (score 0):

Is your code complete? There is nothing on your class that make an http request, the rest seems to be fine.
Try to use Okhttp it's really simple. Check it [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

That thread sleep will run in main thread which is not such good idea.Use post execute to run you callback and publish any results.